# How to do push from clone repository to Remote server respository using http/ssh protocol?

Tags: mercurial, push

I have following windows configuration:

Windows machine "A" has mercurial repository.
hg server is running on "A" http

I created clone of "A" on windows machine "B"
After adding and commitng my changes in to clone, I want to push these changes to machine "A". Tried TortoiseHg: synchronize -> Push option, but getting below error:

```
pushing to http://praveen@IP Addr:8001/
searching for changes
1 changesets found
ssl required
[command returned code 1]
```

Then I did below changes in the machine "A" /.hg/hgrc file

```
  [web]
  push_ssl = False
  allow_push = *
```

and again I tried hg push from machine "B" but getting same error.

can anyone solve my problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Praveen

Answer (score 3):

What you've done looks right to me.  I can think of two things that might be wrong.

1. Did you restart the HTTP server on A after changing the `hgrc` file?

<strike>2. I don't know if `hgrc` is case-sensitive but try the setting as</strike>

```
`push_ssl = false`
```

because I've always seen it written that way.

Comment: I res-started the HTTP server of machine "A" and problem resolved. Now able to push over http protocoal from remote clone. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The boolean values are not case-sensitive and you can use "1", "yes", "true", "on", for True and "0", "no", "false", "off" for False.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  I didn't think it was case sensitive so it's good to know for sure now.